# Query 1 million records from MySQL into an array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

My end goal is sending 3 million records to the Google Maps API to show as markers, but before I get to that..

I haven't been able to even load up 1 million into a PHP array. The data is 18 digits for each element, with 2 columns and 1 million rows.

The query is just a straight up `SELECT *`, but I'm running out of memory when looping through and storing the correct records in an array. I've tried using an SplFixedArray but not having any luck with that either.

I need to find a good way to batch this and split it up - After running some tests, I can pull about 500k into an array without hitting the memory limit (which is already 512M!), so could I just do this in 2 or 3 queries? I will still need the full amount of data saved into arrays on the server side before the page loads and I can pass it to Maps, so I'm assuming batching it won't fix that as it will all still be in memory?

edit: there's a big comment chain growing, but mostly everyone is in agreement that this is a bad idea for some reason or another. So *my* solution is to draw it back to about 300k points, which will be achievable with a lot less head bashing.

Comment: Don't do it..... large volumes of data take large volumes of memory. To give you some idea of how much memory you are going to need, [read this](https://nikic.github.io/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html).... then stop trying to DDOS the Google Maps API

Comment: @MarkBaker so this just straight up isn't possible? Not being rude but I am curious. And I shouldn't be DOSing anything, it's loading the array on my own site and then loading it into gmap - I didn't think that would cause Google additional server load

Comment: If you're hitting Google Maps API with a request for plotting 3000000 data points, then that's going to be rejected by google as though it was an attack..... have you come across any businesses that try to do it with this volume of data? There's a good reason why they don't

Comment: Yes it could be done, it would require large amounts of memory(did you read the page I pointed you to that describes how to calculate the memory requirement)..... it simply isn't practical (or sensible)..... why do you feel the need to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't me that feels the need to do this, it's a client request

Comment: As far as my experience goes gmaps with a lot of points will be pretty slow and not comfortable to use. Try to generate your 3M random markers, put them to map and try to use it. My guess is that your browser will crash. Maybe it would be better (and definitely more complicated) to group your markers based on the zoom level into only one marker and when zooming in loading new points with ajax but based on the current coordinations.

Comment: Then perhaps you need to have a word with your client about the impracticalities of what they're requesting.... surely you've seen how other sites do this, typically summarising the count of points in a region until you zoom in on that region, so that only a limited number of points are actually ever plotted at any request

Comment: @Tom sometimes you gotta say No to a client. After all, you are the expert they hired.You know how to come up with a feasible solution. And it's not the one they are asking for.

Comment: @MarkBaker I'm absolutely fine with clustering the points or some other library to consolidate the stress of 3 million points, it's more just getting the data there in the first place

Comment: @Gordon I think I will have to deny this one, this was my last straw attempt at a feasible solution haha

Comment: @Tom can you elaborate more on "I will still need the full amount of data saved into arrays on the server side before the page loads and I can pass it to Maps". I still don't get why you need that.

Comment: I can not blieve that the client literally asked to dump 3 million data points to gmaps. Instead he asked for visualizing certain facts on maps - or should have better. You need some zooming approach and even then I would stream the result - one row from the db send to maps, next row and so forth - instead of trying to pull that in to memory.

Comment: @AxelAmthor not that it matters, but the client specifically asked to see 3.2 million points on a zoomed out (i.e. you can see it all at once) map of the UK. They don't want zooming and I'm not sure they even want clustering, which is why I was a bit stuck. Until I binned the original request

Comment: @Gordon I was struggling to visualise how to pass the data without loading it all at once. This has been a long day as you can probably tell

Comment: @Tom Based on my observations of this comment thread, you will not find an answer on stackoverflow. Also, any answer would be too long to post here.

Comment: Try in on php 7, it might work,it would be nice if you will edit your question with the results https://nikic.github.io/2014/12/22/PHPs-new-hashtable-implementation.html

Comment: @Mihai I might have a try at home, I definitely can't put PHP7 on a live client site right now though.

Comment: Considering a usual UHD monitor where the UK fits in verticaly and thus only uses a third of the width of the monitor but its full height, 3.2 mio datapoints then would mean almost two datapoints per pixel in an even distribution. A heatmap is what's coming up my mind regarding these statistics

Answer (score 3):

There really isn't any point trying to pump millions of map markers to google maps.

It simply isn't feasible from a memory perspective or a performance perspective. Just think of the size of that data -- even if each marker is only a single byte of data, that's 3 megabytes. But in reality, each marker will need about 20 bytes minimum, just for the co-ords and the JSON markup, so that's 60 megabytes, before you even start adding a description to each one. Your system isn't going to be able to transfer that to Google anything like fast enough to make it usable on the web. And even if you could, Google isn't going to accept you sending that kind of volumne of data to them every time someone wants to look at your map.

And in any case, having all those markers on the map wouldn't be usable anyway; they'd obscure the whole map and each other, and just make a mess.

Even sending a few hundred map markers to Google at once is pushing it. Sending millions is just not going to happen.

So what can you do instead? How do other sites manage to have thousands of millions of markers at once? The answer is simple -- they don't. They only send markers to Google for the portion of the map that is being displayed.

At wider zoom levels, you don't even display markers; you'd have a pre-rendered heat-map showing where your coverage is. At closer zoom levels, you would only load the map pins for the area being displayed. As the map is moved, you would load more.

A good example of what I mean is the [Xfinity wifi map](http://hotspots.wifi.xfinity.com/). They've hundreds of thousands of points on the map, but never load more than a few dozen markers at once. Quick and manageable.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth response, the prerendered heat map is a great idea, it is very in line with the end result I need, so I will look into it some more

Answer (score 1):

Laying the issue of whether fetching 1 M records into the client is a good idea, and assuming that it is necessary. It is important to understand how MySQL client protocol works. There are two modes - one stores the entire data set at once in the client (`STORE_RESULT`) with the memory allocated for the entire set, while the other fetches one row at a time with the memory allocated for just the current row (`USE_RESULT`). To avoid the memory problem your client needs to employ the `USE_RESULT` mode.

For some examples, take a look at:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php

You want unbuffered query.